# running tally for dice game

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice, cumulative-sum

I am one week into a coding bootcamp so forgive my simplistic and probably sloppy coding, but I was wondering how I could put in a running tally of wins for my two player dice rolling game. I am able to produce the final score and loop the function back around to start again if the players want to keep playing but I would like to keep a running tally of wins so the players know how many times each player has won. Here is my function:

```
def DiceRoll():
    Dice1 = random.randint(1, 20)
    Dice2 = random.randint(1, 12)
    Dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
    Dice4 = random.randint(1, 20)
    Dice5 = random.randint(1, 12)
    Dice6 = random.randint (1, 6)
    DoubleDice1 = (((Dice1 + Dice2)*2) + Dice3)
    DoubleDice2 = (((Dice1 + Dice3)*2) + Dice2)
    DoubleDice3 = (((Dice2 + Dice3)*2) + Dice1)
    DoubleDice4 = (((Dice4 + Dice5)*2) + Dice6)
    DoubleDice5 = (((Dice4 + Dice6)*2) + Dice5)
    DoubleDice6 = (((Dice5 + Dice6)*2) + Dice4)
    TripleDice1 = ((Dice1 + Dice2 +Dice3) * 3)
    TripleDice2 = ((Dice4 + Dice5 +Dice6) * 3)

    print("Player 1, Roll?")
    Roll = input("Y/N?")
    if Roll =="y":
        print("Ok!")
    if Roll == "n":
        print("Goodbye!")
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.exit(0)
    print("             ")
    print(Dice1, Dice2, Dice3)
    Score1 = Dice1 + Dice2 + Dice3
    if Dice1 == Dice2:
        Score1 = DoubleDice1
        print(Score1)
    elif Dice1 ==Dice3:
        Score1 = DoubleDice2
        print(Score1)
    elif Dice2 == Dice3:
        Score1 = DoubleDice3
        print(Score1)
    elif Dice1 == Dice2 ==Dice3:
        Score1 = TripleDice1
        print(Score1)
    else:
        print(Dice1 + Dice2 + Dice3)
    print("""   
            """)

    print("Player 2, Roll?")
    Roll2 = input("Y/N?")
    if  Roll2 =="y":
        print("Ok!")
    if Roll2 == "n":
        print("Goodbye!")
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.exit(0)
    print("             ")
    print(Dice4, Dice5, Dice6)
    Score2 = (Dice4 + Dice5 + Dice6)
    if Dice4 == Dice5:
        Score2 = DoubleDice4
        print(Score2)
    elif Dice4 == Dice6:
        Score2 = DoubleDice5
        print(Score2)
    elif Dice5 == Dice6:
        Score2 = DoubleDice6
        print(Score2)
    elif Dice4 == Dice5 ==Dice6:
        Score2 = TripleDice2
        print(Score2)
    else:
        print(Dice4 + Dice5 + Dice6)
    print("""   
            """)
    if Score1 > Score2:
        print("Player 1:", Score1, "Player 2:", Score2)
        print("Player 1 Wins!")
    if Score1 < Score2:
        print("Player 1:", Score1, "Player 2:", Score2)
        print("Player 2 Wins!")
    if Score1 == Score2:
        print("Player 1:", Score1, "Player 2:", Score2)
        print("Tie!")
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but here's some code cleanup ideas: `dice = [random.randint(1, 20) for _ in range(6)]` should simplify your six variables into one

Comment: where do you actually call `DiceRoll`?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no loop in your function, I assume that you have that control loop in the program that calls DiceRoll.  To make a clean tally, you'll need to return the win/lose designation to that program, something like this:

```
if Score1 > Score2:
    print("Player 1:", Score1, "Player 2:", Score2)
    print("Player 1 Wins!")
    winner = 1
elif Score1 < Score2:
    print("Player 1:", Score1, "Player 2:", Score2)
    print("Player 2 Wins!")
    winner = 2
else:
    print("Player 1:", Score1, "Player 2:", Score2)
    print("Tie!")
    winner = 0
```

Now, back in your main program, we'll have something like:

```
p1_wins = 0
p2_wins = 0
ties = 0

while game_on:
    result = DiceRoll()
    if result == 1:
        p1_wins += 1
    elif result = 2
        p2_wins += 1
    else:
        ties += 1
```

I've kept this at the level of programming I think you're using.  *First* you get to understand it.  In a few more boot camp sessions, come back to see how you'd like to improve your coding.

Comment: Where would I define game_on?

Comment: Above the while loop.  This is just a boolean flag that indicates whether the players have decided to continue playing.  You said you already know how to loop to keep the game going.  Since you didn't provide that code, I made up a canonical one.

Answer (score 1):

The most simplistic solution would be to have the DiceRoll function return which player won.

```
winner = None
if Score1 > Score2:
    print("Player 1:", Score1, "Player 2:", Score2)
    print("Player 1 Wins!")
    winner = 1
elif Score1 < Score2:
    print("Player 1:", Score1, "Player 2:", Score2)
    print("Player 2 Wins!")
    winner = 2
elif Score1 == Score2:
    print("Player 1:", Score1, "Player 2:", Score2)
    print("Tie!")
    winner = 0
return winner
```

Then in the loop that calls DiceRoll, just check the returned result.

Now, you've got a lot of repeated code in this function.  You're basically doing everything twice.  This makes it a prime candidate for breaking into another function.  I would suggest making a function that takes the player as a parameter, and then does the dice rolls for just that player, and returns the score.  Then you could just call the function for each player, compare the results, and determine the winner from that.

One last thing.  If a player chooses not to roll, it's exiting the program.  That should probably be changed to be considered a forfeit, and have it exit at the outer loop so you can display the final tally.